# Setting an AVMIDIPlayer's currentPosition would stop all currently playing notes from playing

Tags: swift

In Swift, when I set an AVMIDIPlayer's currentPosition, all currently playing notes stop playing, even if they're tied to the same note at the new position. Any fix or workaround, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No fix, methinks. If you want to go to the new position directly, you lose all notes. If you don't want to lose the notes, try setting the rate high and back, but it takes some time to reach the new position...